# custom icon in ios6 doesn't show in device

Tags: ios6, icons

I think my question is very simple but I have search the stackover and can't find ,maybe it's because I don't know how to use  key words.

the question is in IOS6,I have develop an app that has custom icons,it show fine in simulator,but on real device it still show the old icon that given by system.I can't figure why this happen ,thanks for your help and if you can give me a link to the answer that in this website also thank you too.:D

Comment: Are you talking about app icons?

Comment: @NSIllusion that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your app from your device & re install the ipa.